# Github jakejarvis/s3-sync-action failing

Tags: amazon-s3, github-actions, cicd

here is the error message I get in github actions:

`fatal error: An error occurred () when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation:` 

[image: github action error]

this my bucket permission :
<br:>

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_title",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_title/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You didn't include the actual error code e.g. AccessDenied. That aside, you may want to report this as an issue at the relevant github repo so the owners can help you.

Comment: that's all I got in the logs  
```fatal error: An error occurred () when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation:```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, be aware that your bucket policy is probably incorrect. The S3 sync is happening with AWS credentials so you do not need to allow s3:PutObject, s3:PutObjectAcl, s3:DeleteObject, or s3:ListBucket to the world in your bucket policy. The policy, as written, is dangerous. Simply give those permissions on this bucket to the IAM user whose credentials your sync is using.